# Understanding the MeshShading options

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, inequalities, intersection

The following code draws the intersection of a surface `N: eqNcar=0` with three other surfaces defined by `eq1=0`, `eq2=0`, `eq3=0`.

I would like to shade with dots a specific region on $N$ namely the region defined by $\{eq1>0\}, \{eq2>0\} \cap \{eq3<0\}$.
I would like to use the option `MeshShading` but I don't understand what tensor I should put. The documentation says an array of depth $k$ (here $k=3$ because I have $3$ mesh functions) but such specification raises an error (like "bad tensor dimension"). Anyway I am fighting with what to put in the structure of `MeshShading`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

nn          = 3;
eps         = Table[Subscript[ep,i],{i,nn}];
xs          = Table[Subscript[x,i],{i,nn}];
alp         = 1/2;
bet         = 2;
Subscript[ep,2] = -alp Subscript[ep,1]/bet;
Subscript[ep,1] = 1;
Subscript[ep,3] = 0;

eqNcar      = -(1 + alp + bet)^(-1) - ((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) - Subscript[x, 1])^2 - ((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) - Subscript[x, 2])^2 + Subscript[x, 3];
eqNpar      = {w,s,w^2+s^2} + 1/(1+ alp+bet) {1,1,1};

eq1         = (-((1 + (1 + alp + bet)*s^2 + (1 + alp + bet)*w^2)*\
    (bet*s + s^2 + w*(alp + w))) + 2*s*(1 + (1 + alp + bet)*s)*\
   (s + alp*s^2 + w*(bet + alp*w)) + 2*w*(1 + (1 + alp + bet)*w)*\
   (alp*s + w + bet*(s^2 + w^2)))/(1 + alp + bet); 

eq2         = (alp*(-s + w)*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + s^2 + w^2) -
  (2*w*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + w)*(-(alp^2*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + s)) +
     bet*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + w)))/bet -
  (2*s*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + s)*(-(alp*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + s)) +
     bet^2*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + w)))/bet)*Subscript[ep, 1];

eq3 = (-3/(1 + alp + bet) + s + 2*w)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
 ((-2 + alp + bet)*(3 + (1 + alp + bet)^2*s^2 + (1 + alp + bet)*s*
      (-3 + (1 + alp + bet)*w) + (1 + alp + bet)*w*
      (-3 + (1 + alp + bet)*w)) + (1 + alp + bet)*(-3 + 2*(1 + alp + bet)*s + 
     (1 + alp + bet)*w)*Subscript[ep, 2])/(1 + alp + bet)^2;

pN = ParametricPlot3D[eqNpar,{w,-1,1},{s,-1,1},\
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x,y,z,w,s},(eqNcar/. Thread[xs->eqNpar])-eq1],\
    Function[{x,y,z,w,s},(eqNcar/. Thread[xs->eqNpar])-eq2],\
    Function[{x,y,z,w,s},(eqNcar/. Thread[xs->eqNpar])-eq3]},\
  MeshStyle -> {{Blue},{Red},{Black}},\
  MeshShading->{
    {{Automatic,Automatic,Automatic}},\
    {{Automatic,Automatic,Automatic}},\
    {{HalftoneShading[],Automatic,Automatic}}
  },
  Mesh -> {{0}},PlotStyle->Orange,PlotPoints->200,
  BoundaryStyle->{1->None},\
  AxesLabel->xs
 ];

cm              = 72/2.54;
image       = Rasterize[Show[pN,ImageSize->10 cm],"Image",ImageResolution->800];
Export["ex.pdf", Show[image, ImageSize -> 10 cm]]
```

In my example, `MeshShading` is an array $M$ of size $(1,3,3)$ and of depth $4$ (note the documentation would expect a array of depth $3$) and I was expecting the coefficient $m_{1ij}$ to be the color of the region between the ith meshcurves and jth mesh curve but it is not the case.

ps: I would like the method to be easily adaptable for a number of mesh functions up to $10$.

Comment: What is `xf` in the code?

Comment: I corrected, it's `eqNpar`

Comment: Since your three `MeshFunctions` are difference from the three functions `eq1,eq2,eq3`, we can only use `RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y, z, w, s}, eq1 > 0 && eq2 > 0 && eq3 < 0]`. to get the region `eq1 > 0 && eq2 > 0 && eq3 < 0`. and the rest region by `RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y, z, w, s}, ! (eq1 > 0 && eq2 > 0 && eq3 < 0)]`.

Comment: If `ms` is the `MeshShading` tensor, then its depth should equal the number of mesh functions. At level `j`, `ms[[..., j0, ...]]` is a directive that applies when the $j$-th mesh function lies between `j0-1` and `j0` values of `Mesh` division points (with the indices `...` at the other levels depending on the values of the other mesh functions). Notes: 1. If `j0 == 1`, then the division point corresponding to `j0-1` is `-Infinity`. 2. If the dimension of the mesh shading tensor at level `j` is less than 1 plus the number of division points, then the mesh shading tensor is cyclically extended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how `MeshShading` is supposed to work. The way it works is as follows: You give a set of `MeshFunctions` $\{f_1, f_2, \dots\}$, and a set of mesh divisions $\{\{d_{1,1},d_{1,2},\dots\},\{d_{2,1},d_{2,2},\dots\},\dots\}$ (effectively the setting of `Mesh`, i.e. the values of $f_1,\dots$ that where mesh contours should be drawn). The mesh divisions effectively define intervals as
$$\{\{I_{1,1},I_{1,2},\dots\},\{I_{2,1},I_{2,2},\dots\},\dots\}=\{\{(-\infty,c_{1,1}],(c_{1,1},c_{1,2}],\dots\},\{(-\infty,c_{2,1}],(c_{2,1},c_{2,2}],\dots\},\dots\}.$$

This means that every point can be assigned to a set of intervals $\{I_{1,i},I_{2,j},\dots\}$, whose style is given by the entry $m_{i,j,\dots}$ from the `MeshShading` option.

To illustrate this, consider the following:

```
With[{plot = 
   ParametricPlot3D[eqNpar, {w, -1, 1}, {s, -1, 1}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, w, 
        s}, (eqNcar /. Thread[xs -> eqNpar]) - eq1], 
      Function[{x, y, z, w, s}, (eqNcar /. Thread[xs -> eqNpar]) - 
        eq2], Function[{x, y, z, w, 
        s}, (eqNcar /. Thread[xs -> eqNpar]) - eq3]}, 
    MeshStyle -> {{Blue}, {Red}, {Black}}, 
    MeshShading -> 
     SparseArray[{{i_, j_, k_} :> style[i, j, k]}, {2, 2, 2}, 
      Directive[]], Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
    PlotPoints -> 200, BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None}, AxesLabel -> xs]},
 Manipulate[
  plot /. 
   style[i_, j_, k_] :> 
    If[{i, j, k} == {i0, j0, k0}, Green, Directive[]],
  {i0, 1, 2, 1},
  {j0, 1, 2, 1},
  {k0, 1, 2, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

As you can see, the first slider selects which "side" of the black mesh line you are on, the second which side of the red mesh line, and the third slider which side of the blue mesh line you are on.